# Unable to access tomcat server running in container from browser

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers

Hello I have recently started learning docker. I tried to connect to tomcat server in docker desktop using

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest
```

I tried to access the server using localhost:8080 and the docker container ip address but nothing worked.

HTTP Status error

[image]

I also checked the logs but there were no issue. what should i do now?

Comment: Make sure the binding IP of your tomcat server is 0.0.0.0 inside your container.

Comment: yes the binding address is set to 0.0.0.0. But still don't know what is the issue. I encountered the same issue with mysql container too.

Comment: Also, is the binding port for tomcat 8080?

Comment: yes it is set to 8080. I even tried by changing the ports.

Comment: Hi! From what I can see, Tomcat is working, but it responds with 404 because it cannot find the file/resource you requested. What URL are you requesting? Are you sure that the server is serving that?

Comment: First i  was checking whether I was able to access the tomcat home page or not. Then I icreated a simple hello world servlet application and deployed it on the tomcat. Yet the results are same. I have followed all the steps from multiple youtube videos.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tomcat image doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat#:%7E:text=it%20will%20return%20a%20404%20since%20there%20are%20no%20webapps%20loaded%20by%20default) says

> it will return a 404 since there are no webapps loaded by default

so this is the expected behavior.

Note, however, that it is not correct to say that you are "unable to access Tomcat server" because the 404 error is reported by Tomcat, as confirmed by the footer in your screenshot.